# Retrieve the rest of a line from a search

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a file with these lines :

```
BDD_USER=use
BDD_PASS=password
BDD_NAME=database
```

I would like to get the password beside BDD_PASS=

Currently i'm trying grep command to retrieve this from Linux shell.

Like : `grep 'BBD_PASS='`

But this return the entire line i don't find any switch to get only the password.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: awk -F'=' '/BDD_PASS/ {print $1}' name_of_file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
grep -oP 'BDD_PASS=\K.*' file
```